# Laravel: How to make user able to take test even if connection is interrupted

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing an online examination portal in Laravel. I need to have a feature in which while taking test and navigating through the questions if the internet connection is lost, the user should be able to continue the test and when the connection comes back he only has to submit the test. can anyone please guide me what should i do to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Major browsers support the `window.navigator.onLine` property along with associated events. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine . You can use this to detect and enable/disable the submit button of your test. The rest of the test should work as normal as long as it doesn't require a connection for e.g. ajax requests.

Comment: @apokryfos my problem is not that i want to detect the connectivity of browser. my problem is to make user able to take test and answer the questions(which are stored in database with the correct answer)  even if the connection is lost. Thanks for your reply. 

Comment: When the user loads the page with the test they will require a connection, however they can still interact with the test even if the connection is lost after the page was loaded. My comment was on how you can ensure that there is a connection before the user actually submits their responses.

Comment: Yes exactly. but if question is coming from database, will there be any problem loading question from database or is there a way to load all questions with correct answer at once and how to store the chosen options until the network resumes? Please clarify.

Comment: You can load all questions when the test is loaded and then just show one question at a time to the user and keep their answers for each question on the client-side before you can submit them all. Usually people use JavaScript MVVM frameworks to do this like React, Vue, Angular or Knockout. Don't load the correct answers though because then the person doing the test can just find them in the JavaScript code